# Top align cell in longtable with variable height

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I have a `longtable` with two columns. The first I need to be top aligned, the second needs to be middle aligned. The text is populated by a script, so the height will vary (I'm writing a template, not a document per se). Anyway, the problem is that the first column is middle aligned instead of top aligned, and all the solutions I've found are for fixed height cells (as in the text is known).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage[bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \small
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.35}
        {\footnotesize \begin{longtable}{p{5.6cm}m{11.5cm}}
            \textbf{Something} & Some other thing. \\
            \textbf{Something here} & Just one line. \\
            \textbf{Something larger goes here, so this actually occupies two lines} & Some multiline text \newline Some multiline text \newline Some multiline text \newline Some multiline text \\
            \textbf{This one is shorter} & Some multiline text \newline Some multiline text \newline Some multiline text \newline Some multiline text \\
        \end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

What I need is this:

[image]

Comment: why do you have a minipage? m and p columns are essentially parboxes already and allow multi-line text.

Comment: unrelated to the question but never put `longtable` in a `center` environment, it doesn't centre it, just adds spurious vertical space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The minipages are there because the text may contain line breaks `\\ `. Didn't know about `center` being problematic with `longtable`, thanks for the comment ;)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by saying the first column is top aligned and the second is middle aligned, your image shows that is the case here so you do not mean what tex means,  since you ask for something different. Each row of the longtable has a single baseline through all columns, top aligned entries place their top line on this baseline, middle aligned entries place their vertical centre on the baseline. which is why the baseline of the first row in your left column is at the same position as the centre of the second column.

Comment: you don't need a minipage, you could use `\newline` instead tables change `\\ ` but leave `\newline` (also of course you should not have the final `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I've edited the question acordingly (at least I think so) and added an image of the desired result.

Comment: so I think you just want to change `m` to `p` for the second column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So simple... thanks!! So, should this question be closed? It was such a silly thing after all...

Comment: off-topic: you can write `\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries}p{5.6cm} p{11.5cm}}` and than in the first column omit all `\textbf` commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your first image shows the effect of column specifications `p  m` the top line of each p-cell entry is placed on the (red) baseline of the row, and the vertical centre of the m-cell entries are placed on the baseline.

In the second image the top row of both left and right column entries are placed on the row baseline so to achieve that,  use `p` for both columns.

Comment: I am using p{...} but still facing the same issue?